# HTML/CSS structure collapsing every time JavaScript triggered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really new to coding and I already spent so many hours trying to figure this out:

I have a number of boxes (divs) laid out in a circle, with a button in the middle. When the button is clicked, one of the boxes turns yellow.

The problem is that the layout collapses when the button is clicked, with the boxes stacked in a column. Why is that?

Maybe I should go with the table structure, but I don't think you can do similar design. Please give me your thoughts on that.

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/solosurge/pen/ggKvYN

```js
// ----Timer---->
function countDown(secs, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Please wait for " + secondsToHms(secs) + " seconds";
  secs--;
  var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + secs + ',"' + elem + '")', 1000);
  if (secs < 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    randomPhrase();
  }
  // ----Hour to Min to Sec---->
  function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
    return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
  }
}

// ----Random Pick------>
function randomPhrase() {
  var ids = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");

  while (divs.length > 0) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
    divs[0].id = 'item-' + ids[i];
    ids.splice(i, 1);
    divs = [].slice.call(divs, 1);
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 155px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}

#one {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

#two {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

#three {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

#four {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

#five {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  clear: both;
}

#six {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#seven {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  clear: both;
}

#eight {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

#nine {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

#ten {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

#box1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#item-1 {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div" id="one"></div>
    <div class="div" id="two"></div>
    <div class="div" id="three"></div>
    <div class="div" id="four"></div>
    <div class="div" id="five"></div>
    <div class="div" id="six"></div>
    <div class="div" id="seven"></div>
    <div class="div" id="eight"></div>
    <div class="div" id="nine"></div>
    <div class="div" id="ten"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box1">Click<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="countDown(3,'box1');">Here</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem?  You styled by the `id` but are changing the `id` so the divs stack on top of one another. How do you expect the page to behave when you click the button?

Comment: structure should stay the same with yellow box filled in

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OWEQYb

Comment: yeah, exactly like this! what did you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're styling everything circularly via an `id` value. Then you're re-assigning new ID's to the divs in `randomPhrase()`, which breaks the layout. In `randomPhrase()`, instead of assigning ID's, assign classes, then style the yellow item via a classname instead so that your ID-based CSS layout still works.

```js
// ----Timer---->
function countDown(secs, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Please wait for " + secondsToHms(secs) + " seconds";
  secs--;
  var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + secs + ',"' + elem + '")', 1000);
  if (secs < 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    randomPhrase();
  }
  // ----Hour to Min to Sec---->
  function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
    return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
  }
}

// ----Random Pick------>
function randomPhrase() {
  var ids = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");

  while (divs.length > 0) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
    divs[0].classList.add('item-' + ids[i]);
    ids.splice(i, 1);
    divs = [].slice.call(divs, 1);
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 155px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}

#one {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

#two {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

#three {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

#four {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

#five {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  clear: both;
}

#six {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#seven {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  clear: both;
}

#eight {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

#nine {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

#ten {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

#box1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="div" id="one"></div>
    <div class="div" id="two"></div>

    <div class="div" id="three"></div>
    <div class="div" id="four"></div>
    <div class="div" id="five"></div>

    <div class="div" id="six"></div>
    <div class="div" id="seven"></div>
    <div class="div" id="eight"></div>

    <div class="div" id="nine"></div>
    <div class="div" id="ten"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="box1">Click<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="countDown(3,'box1');">Here</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```